# GWT listbox - how to look up item index using text?

Tags: java, gwt

Is there anyway to look up an item's index number using the item text in GWT listbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, you have to iretare thru them and find that index yourself.

Like this:

```
String text = "listBoxText";
int indexToFind = -1;
for (int i=0; i<listBox.getItemCount(); i++) {
    if (listBox.getItemText(i).equals(text)) {
        indexToFind = i;
        break;
    }
}
```