# Find by String in a GWT ListBox

Tags: string, gwt, listbox, find

I would like to find the index of an item inside a GWT Listbox by specifying a String value.

For example, if I had a GWT ListBox comprising the following items: "Randy", "Bob" and "Helen", the method i'm looking to implement would return the value `1` if I called it with parameter `"Bob"`.

From what i'm seeing in the ListBox javadoc, ther does not seem to be any quick method to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this one..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986793/gwt-listbox-how-to-look-up-item-index-using-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea of implementation as TextBox doesn't provide this out of the box. Store all the items in a list and in the order you want them to be part of ListBox.

```
List<String> orderedItems=new ArrayList<String>

orderedItems.add(0,"Randy");
orderedItems.add(1,"Bob");
orderedItems.add(2,"Helen");

//adding items in the same order as they are in List is the key
for(String item:items)
{
   lb.addItem(item);
}
```

then you can find the index using [List's indexOf(..) method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Adding a whole new data structure just do that isn't a very good idea.